# Check using reflection if property is IEnumerable only of reference types but not string or value types

Tags: c#, reflection

Hello I need to check using reflection whether property is `IEnumerable` type but not IEnumerable of string and value types, but only IEnumerable of non-string reference types.

Right now I have that part of code:

```
private bool IsEnumerable(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    return propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)) &&
           propertyInfo.PropertyType != typeof(string);
}
```

If property is `IEnumerable<MyCustomType>` this is ok, but if it is `IEnumerable<string>` my method **should** return false.

Comment: you want [Type.GetGenericArguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What if it both `IEnumerable<MyCustomType>` and `IEnumerable<string>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect the [GenericTypeArguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.generictypearguments.aspx) of the implemented `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces on the type to ensure that it is both not of type string and not a value type:

```
public static bool IsEnumerable(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    var propType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

    var ienumerableInterfaces = propType.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
                        typeof(IEnumerable<>)).ToList();

    if (ienumerableInterfaces.Count == 0) return false;

    return ienumerableInterfaces.All(x => 
                x.GenericTypeArguments[0] != typeof(string) &&
                !x.GenericTypeArguments[0].IsValueType);    
}
```

This updated version appropriately handles cases where there are multiple `IEnumerable<T>` definitions, where there is no `IEnumerable<T>` definition, and where the type of the generic implementing class does not match the type parameter of implemented `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: One more thing: `public IEnumerable<object> P5 { get; set; }`.

Comment: @PetSerAl I would argue that is not what the OP requested since it doesn't implement the interface.

Comment: but for me not working, I pass value like func(T values). In values one of the item type is system.object for this i have two values in array. i want determine this . I tried your code. Any help for this?

Comment: @PraneshJanarthanan create a new question with your example. I’ll be happy to take a look.